# Append output from code to row it came from in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ive got some code which is working to create the output but id like to tack it back onto the row it came from, I'm struggling to do it with a join because there isn't a unique identifier so ideally would like to clean this step up.

first bit of code creates recent_transactions and then id like to append onto the end of each row the output from class_df

```
recent_transactions = pd.DataFrame(data)
recent_transactions

class_df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(i['unknownStatementItem']) for i in recent_transactions.itemClassData)
```

Comment: 1- add a `pandas` tag in your post. 2- you have to provide your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique identifier by using the index entry of a dataframe that has no duplicate index numbers.  You can reset the index to guarantee a clean index with no duplicates.  Ideally you can use vectorization rather than iteration, but at worst, get the unique index number from the dataframe and use it to find the correct row for setting a new column to the function's output.

```
row1list = [1, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list],
                  columns=['a', 'b'])

df = df.append(df)  # duplicate index numbers, so clean that up next
print(df)
#    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 0  1  2

df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()  
# drop old index with duplicates, make new clean 'index' and make it available as a column
print(df)
#    index  a  b
# 0      0  1  2
# 1      1  1  2

df['result_of_some_function'] = -1  # start with a bogus value, upgrade as appropriate
for i in range(len(df)):
    result_of_some_function = i * 2
    df.loc[df['index'] == i, 'result_of_some_function'] = result_of_some_function

print(df)
#    index  a  b  result_of_some_function
# 0      0  1  2                        0
# 1      1  1  2                        2
```